# How to replace Thread.join with Semaphores in java on a concrete example

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Semaphores in Java and I wonder if someone could show me how to replace join in this program with the Semaphore so that the program works the same:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class JoinP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberofthreads = 10;
        Thread[] t = new Thread[numberofthreads];

        for (int j = 0; j < numberofthreads; j++) {
            (t[j] = new Thread( new ExThread() )).start();
        }

        try {
            for (int k = 0; k < numberofthreads; k++) t[k].join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return; 
        }
    }

    static class ExThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: If you want to change the way in which two threads interact,  you usually will have to change _both_ of the threads.

Comment: Could you be more specific, is there any way for Main thread to use Semaphore to wait for all threads to be done and then do something after that?

Comment: `t.join()` waits until the thread `t` has finished its work. `sem.acquire()` waits until some other thread calls `sem.release()` (assuming that the Semaphore, `sem`, has zero permits at the time when `sem.acquire()` is called.) So, what if there was no `join()` function? What could thread `t` do to a semaphore, `sem`, so that the main thread could wait for thread `t` to finish its work?

Comment: P.S., `catch(Exception e){return;}` is always a Bad Idea because if an exception happens that you weren't expecting, your program will behave in some way that you weren't expecting, and you won't know why. Instead of simply `return`ing from the `catch` clause or doing nothing in a `catch` clause, you should at least call `e.printStackTrace()`. Then, if an exception happens, your program will print the details of the exception to its standard error output stream, and that will give you a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: Even though you can try to use `Semaphor`s instead of `join`, its goal is to limit concurrency, not to wait until something is done. For waiting multiple tasks there is dedicated class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html